# sed command to delete a string containing / ,\ characters

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a String

```
/abc/gef        \*(cse,fff)
```

to delete from a file,have to match the full string pattern,tried with

```
sed -i '//abc/gef        \*(cse,fff)/d' filename
```

but this ends in an error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char xx: expected newer version of sed

I also tried the following options but didn't work:

```
sed -i '/\/abc\/gef        \*(cse,fff)/d' filename
sed -i 's|/abc/gef        \*(cse,fff)||g' filename
```

What is the right command for this?

Comment: I am able to execute upto below expreseeion 
sed -i '/\/abc\/gef        \\*/d' filename

BUT
when i include "("  like ---

sed -i '/\/var\/nfs        \\*(cse,fff)/d' filename

it's not deleting

Comment: how to escape the "(" and ")" ?
DO i need to escape "," also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both `\` (escape character) and `*` (0 or more) have a special meaning in regular expressions, so you need to *escape* them in order to use them as literal characters. Now, the way to escape something is to add a `\` before it. So, in order for `*` to match a literal asterisk and not mean "0 or more", you would write `\*`. Similarly, to escape the `\` you would write `\\`. Putting this together, we have:

```
$ cat file 
foo
bar
/abc/gef        \*(cse,fff)
baz
```

And:

```
$ sed '/\/abc\/gef        \\\*(cse,fff)/d' file 
foo
bar
baz
```

Note how I have also escaped the `/` since `//` is the match operator in `sed`. This is why we have `/\/abc\/gef` and not `//abc/gef`. The `d` at the end means "delete any line matching this pattern".

Answer (score 2):

The following works with GNU sed versions 4.5 and 4.7 and will delete any lines that contain the string:

```
sed '/\/abc\/gef        \\\*(cse,fff)/d' file
```

You have to use `\` to escape the two instances of `/` in the string so that they aren't taken as the delimiter and `*` which otherwise expands to the character before it which is `f`. The latter will cause it not to match the string.

You can also use the `s` option which allows other characters as a delimiter if you only want to delete the string itself throughout the file and not the entire line:

```
sed 's|/abc/gef        \\\*(cse,fff)||g' file
```

That uses `|` as a delimiter so that you don't have to escape `/`.

To edit the file in place after you're sure that it does what you want, you can use `-i` like you have above:

```
sed -i '/\/abc\/gef        \\\*(cse,fff)/d' file

sed -i 's|/abc/gef        \\\*(cse,fff)||g' file
```

EDIT: I have updated the answer as the string in the question is different from what it was when originally posted.

Comment: You may also use almost any other character as a  delimiter in the `s` command, getting rid of the need for escaping the slashes.

Comment: IT's not giving the error but not deleting from the file the exact string to delete ---
/abc/gef        \*(cse,fff)

after gef 4,5 blankspaces are present but it's not showing here

Comment: The `/.../d` version deletes the entire line that contains the string, though, not just the string.

Comment: yes I want to delete the entire line

Comment: Tried with below options but didn't work--- 

sed -i '/\/abc\/gef        \*(cse,fff)/d' filename

sed -i 's|/var/nfs        \*(cse,fff)||g' filename

Comment: @thanasisp I have edited the answer with code for the updated string.

Comment: @Mike See my update. It now matches the change to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for grep:

```bsh
$ cat file
line 1
line 2
/abc/gef        *(cse,fff)
line 4

$ grep -Fxv '/abc/gef        *(cse,fff)' file
line 1
line 2
line 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Glenn